# Preventing corrosion on YL-69

Tags: pi-3, sensor, breadboard

I am using the [YL-69](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015T8BBX2) with a [MCP3008](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) and a Raspberry Pi 3:

[image]

I am using the sensor for soil moisture measurement (plant monitoring). This is the code which gets analogue sensor values:

```
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

def getAdc (channel):
    if ((channel>7)or(channel<0)):
        return -1

    r = spi.xfer([1, (8+channel) << 4,0])

    adcOut = ((r[1]&3) << 8) + r[2]
    percent = int(round(adcOut/10.24))
    return percent

moist_value = getAdc(0)
```

The code is not mine I took it from [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Wiring-up-a-MCP3008-ADC-to-a-Raspberry-Pi-model-B-/). The script is run every 30 minutes via a Cronjob.

I have been watering the plant for about three weeks. Then I suddenly got values like this although I have not been watering for days:

[image]

After further inspection I saw that one of the LEDs on the YL-69 PCB was off. Also one of the pins on the sensor itsef fell off. It looks a lot like corrosion.

I did some [research](https://github.com/eyantrainternship/eYSIP_2015_IoT-Connected-valves-for-irrigation-of-greenhouse/wiki/8.1-Moisture-sensor) and fond that:

> Continuously powering the sensor module will corrode the moisture
>   sensor overtime. Therefore control the power to the moisture sensor
>   using a GPIO pin of ESP8266

So I wonder can I turn the power on and off without using a ESP8266. I dont see any code for setting GPIO pins to high or low, so I suppose that they are set to high on default and I can change them back to low. Would that power off the YL-69?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the chips may draw up to 40mA, we won't be able to power them directly with GPIO.

In this case you may use a [transistor as a switch](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html).
Using this method will allow you to power the circuit with classic 5V/GND pins, controlled  via a GPIO, adding only few common components to your circuit.

If the provided tutorial isn't enough, you will be able to find more help about the circuit on [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Note that corrosion will happen because of current, but also because of moist. Don't forget to protect your connections and pins, at least with glue, or with specific electronic gel.